# Histogram: What is wrong with this code?

Tags: probability, density-function, octave

I've got some issues while trying to plot an histogram using **Octave**, in order to compare it with a p.d.f. given.

1) First of all, I can't find the best way to make an histogram with the frequencies of appearance of each value. I've used the commands below(It is a fragment of the actual code).

2) Also, although at first the histogram was being shown correctly, now it doesn't show up. When I run the code, the plot appears,but it has only the p.d.f. in it.

```
    g=[]; 
    for i=1:ensayos 
            g=[g,TiempoMuerte_Cte(N,c)]; 
    endfor 
    h = hist(g,ensayos,1) 
    hold on 
    x = 0:0.1:30; 
    x_2=exp(-x) - x/(N)- 1; 
    f = N*exp(N*(x_2)); 
    plot(x,f)
```

Am I missing some piece of code?

Thank you very much

Comment: You should specify which software you are using to do this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've put it within the tags, it's OCTAVE. Anyway, I'll edit the post in order to make it clearer. Thank you @GregoryGrant

Comment: 1. Octave code should be vectorized.. Your first simple loop is not. 2. "help hist" to see different usage.

Comment: 1. Do you mean I should avoid using vectors in Octave codes? And why do you say the loop ins't a loop? I haven't had problems with that part: 
a) The program did give me a return value correctly, as a vector, even though the histogram was not shown.
b) I've tried writing 
` hist(g,ensayos,1) ` instead of ` h=hist(g,ensayos,1) ` and it worked.

Comment: No, you should *use* vectors and avoid using loops as much as possible. It's not a question of correctness but efficiency. Huge gains for vectorized code in Matlab/Octave. Google for specific examples of vectorization.